# Extract string showing maximum value in a list of tuple with duplicated elements

Tags: python

I have the following simplified data structure :

```
input = [("FileName1", "ID1", "Sequence1", 1000),
         ("FileName1", "ID1", "Sequence2", 500),
         ("FileName1", "ID2", "Sequence3", 1500),
         ("FileName1", "ID2", "Sequence5", 200),
         ("FileName2", "ID1", "Sequence1", 500),
         ("FileName2", "ID1", "Sequence2", 1000)
         ("FileName2", "ID2", "Sequence3", 250),
         ("FileName2", "ID2", "Sequence5", 2000)]
```

Here, a specific *ID* can be linked with several *Sequences* (not always the same number of *Sequences* attributed to a specific *ID*) and several *ID* can be linked with one specific *File Name* (not always the same number of *ID* attributed to a specific *FileName*)

What I would like is to extract the triplet FileName/ID/Sequence with maximum intensity for each ID:

Output:

```
output = [("FileName1", "ID1", "Sequence1"),
          ("FileName1", "ID2", "Sequence3"),
          ("FileName2", "ID1", "Sequence2")
          ("FileName2", "ID2", "Sequence5")]
```

I need at the end one unique sequence (which had the maximum value) for each ID and to get at the same time the FileName because I need all of this information to map them to a dataframe afterwards.

FileNames will no longer have any duplicate ID and one unique sequence will be linked with a specific ID.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You mention dataframe - are you using pandas or is this pure Python?

Comment: The data come from .csv matrix (with columns and rows) but I have decided to use pure python to extract information from this matrix and put it in a list of tuple. I don't really know if this is the best way to do it... After, I will try to map the output list of tuple into a dataframe. "FileName", "ID", will serve only as "mapping reference" (because they are also present in the dataframe where I want to do the mapping) in order to add each sequence in a new column. Normally, the number of tuple in the output list of tuple should corresponds to the number of rows in the other dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools`

**Ex:**

```
import itertools

input = [("FileName1", "ID1", "Sequence1", 1000),
         ("FileName1", "ID1", "Sequence2", 500),
         ("FileName1", "ID2", "Sequence3", 1500),
         ("FileName1", "ID2", "Sequence5", 200),
         ("FileName2", "ID1", "Sequence1", 500),
         ("FileName2", "ID1", "Sequence2", 1000),
         ("FileName2", "ID2", "Sequence3", 250),
         ("FileName2", "ID2", "Sequence5", 2000)]


result = []
for k, v in itertools.groupby(input, lambda x: (x[0], x[1])):
    result.append(max(list(v), key=lambda x: x[-1]))

# OR
# result = [max(list(v), key=lambda x: x[-1]) for k, v in itertools.groupby(input, lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))]  
    
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[('FileName1', 'ID1', 'Sequence1', 1000),
 ('FileName1', 'ID2', 'Sequence3', 1500),
 ('FileName2', 'ID1', 'Sequence2', 1000),
 ('FileName2', 'ID2', 'Sequence5', 2000)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rakesh, it was not properly working at the beginning because I forget to mention in the example provided that the FileName can be mixed between them so I just  .sort()  the input by the FileName and then apply what you suggest and it seems to work. Thank you